# Can't do mutation.destroy after query on component

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs

I use the parse-react library. I do a first query to retrieve data, in an other component I do the same query but with equalTo("user","user connected") all queries works fine but after the second query when I try to do Mutation.Destroy on an item I got this error. 
`UpdateChannel.js:146 Uncaught Error: Object is attached to a nonexistant subscription`
This is short sample code :

AppWrapper.react.js :

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');
var React = require('react');
var Wall = require('./Wall.react.js');
var Gallery = require('./Gallery.react.js');

var contents = [
  <Wall/>,
  <Gallery/>
];

var AppWrapper = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      current_page:0
    };
  },

  changePage:function(pageidx){
    this.setState({
      current_page:pageidx
    });
  },

  change:function(){
    if(this.state.current_page == 0){
      this.setState({
        current_page:1
      });
    }else{
      this.setState({
        current_page:0
      });
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button  onClick={this.change} className="btn btn-primary">change</button>
          {contents[this.state.current_page]}
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = AppWrapper;
```

Wall.react.js

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var React = require('react');
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');


var Wall = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      type:this.props.type
    };
  },

  observe: function() {
    var query = (new Parse.Query("PictureItem")).descending("createdAt").include("user");
    return {
      items:query
    };
  },

  delete:function(){
    var id = this.data.items[0].id;
    ParseReact.Mutation.Destroy(this.data.items[0]).dispatch();
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log(this.data.items);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={this.delete}>T</button>
          <div className="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h1>WALL</h1>
            // Normale I render rows that map this.data.items
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Wall;
```

Gallery.react.js

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var React = require('react');
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');


var Gallery = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

  observe: function() {
      var userPointer = {"__type": "Pointer",
                      "className": "_User",
                      "objectId": "6O8YNufFK9"};
      var query = (new Parse.Query("PictureItem")).descending("createdAt").include("user").equalTo("user",userPointer);

    return {
      items:query
    };
  },

  delete:function(){
    var id = this.data.items[0].id;
    ParseReact.Mutation.Destroy(id).dispatch();
  },

  render: function() {

    console.log(this.data.items);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={this.delete}>T</button>
          <div className="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
              <h1>Gallery</h1>
                // Normale I render rows that map this.data.items
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Gallery;
```

I really don't know what is the problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/59

Try to update your parse-react library.